# android googlemap marker's icon doesn't changed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a Viewpager which have 4 tab and one of the tab has a map.
I'm going to change android GoogleMap marker's icon on run time. I did the following code

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);


        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                /* googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description")).
                        setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.position_icon));*/
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        sydney=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(""))
        .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.position_icon));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

       googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo));
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


});

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
               /* */
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

But unfortunately then i tap on the marker icon, it's changed but after the a few second the previous marker overlap the new marker icon.
the above code is first tab of TabLayout that i said has a map and it's a fragment.

Comment: It is happening because you are adding a new marker whenever your location is changing. When you click on a marker, its icon changes to **logo**, but after a few seconds, the location changes as well and your code adds a new marker with **position_icon** and since the new position is close to the old position, the new marker overlaps with the old one.

Comment: @HarjotSinghOberai do u have any solution to achieve this goal

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @HarjotSinghOberai i want to change map marker icon when the user tap on the marker and on the second tap on googlemap marker icon the camera opened and user can take a pic and so on

Comment: do you want to add a new marker whenever the position changes? or you want the marker to shift to the new position?

Comment: no forget about position. position is great, i want to change marker icon when user click on the marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with above question is that the icon would revoke after it's changed in onClickItem event. so i define a class global property name marker_change and then controlled with simple if statement.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);


        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                /* googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description")).
                        setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.position_icon));*/
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        sydney=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney))
        .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.position_icon));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

marker_change=1;
                return false;
            }
        });

               if(marker_change==1) {

                   googleMap.clear();
                   MarkerOptions mo=new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("please take pic").snippet("apple")
                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.address_icon));

//            googleMap.addMarker(mo).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_new_mark_icon));;
                   googleMap.addMarker(mo).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_new_mark_icon));

                   cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                   googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
               } else {
                   marker_change=0;
               }

    }


});


            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```